# Jquery getJson send $_GET var to retrieve correct json string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this at the top of the getjson url

```
if(isset($_GET['template']) && $_GET['template']=="blue") {
$inifile_path="ctr/subthemes/blue/";
} else {
$inifile_path="ctr/subthemes/fresh-n-clean/";
}
```

And from the main page I have this when I click a link:

```
$('a[id^=color]').bind('click',function(){
            var template = $(this).attr('rel');
            var jsonurl ="http://www.mysite.org/wp-content/themes/ctr-theme/update_genform.php?theme="+template;
            //load current ini color values into the form values
            $.getJSON(jsonurl,function(data) {
```

And the link is:

```
<a href="#" id="color3" rel="blue">Color</a>
```

I don't see what I've possibly done wrong, and I don't know how to test the $_GET output at the json generator.php because its called, well, trough json :\

What can possible be wrong? The above does not work as expected because I suspect the template var is not being correctly submited, since I always get the "else if" result and never a valid match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    if(isset($_GET['theme']) && $_GET['theme']=="blue"){

}
```

Main fault is in  your PHP script. because you used `$_GET['template']`, but you are sending URL parameter as `theme`. So above is the correct solution I think, though I am novice in jquery.

Comment: OMG!!!! :\ I've been up for around 20 hours now... thanks so much for pointing this out... what an idiot thing on my part :(

Comment: @Joricam thanks, friend.Error is part of programmer's life.So carry on.

Comment: programmin is indeed very interesting, putting imperfect error prone beings in charge of building perfect systemas, haha, what a paradox!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing the template parameter as a parameter instead of an explicit query string?

```
$.getJSON('siteUrl', 
 {"theme" : template},
 function(data){
   // callback data from server 
 }
);
```

Comment: I never new I could! Thank you very much, gonna try it out also

Comment: please edit your awnser and remove url, I forget to remove it, just change it to mysite or something. Thanks